# How to set XAML Width in percentage?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, width

I am trying to create a button in XAML with a 80% width, but I can't seem to figure out how. It's apparently not as easy as using Width="80%". I have been thinking this can be done by detecting the screen width somehow and multiply that by 0.8 and use that as the width, but I am not sure how I can do this in XAML. Perhaps this has to be done in the .cs file and then adjust the width from there. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Is it WPF?

If yes, then wrap your control (button) in grid. Then specify the grid column definition.
Example:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:**
Forget to close `<Button>` tag.

Comment: Error 3 A value of type 'Button' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'ColumnDefinitionCollection'. I get that error even without adding the Grid attributes to the button. And once I write Grid. the intelliSense only gives me d:, local:, mc:, x:, xml: and xmlns as valid choices. Trying to figure out whether or not this WPF, but AFAIK it is.

Comment: Perhaps i need an include/using in the <Page> section? I mean to add a schema?

Comment: Don't input your Button in <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> block. Put it inside <Grid> block, but not in <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> block.

Comment: Hail Mary, you're a saint and I am ashamed. Can't follow a 7 line instruction correctly.

Comment: @Tom Glad it worked. It is a pain during first time learning WPF though

Comment: Works like a charm now, allthough it keeps telling me I need a closing tag for element '<Button>'. But the closing tag is there. Time to try to turn it off and on again :P

Answer (score 7):

I think the more proper way would be

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
</Grid>
```

12 grid distribution like bootstrap, it's just about your preference